# CIFS mount won't auto-mount after reboot

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, cifs

I have a rather small but yet annoying issue with my cifs-share.
It mounts just fine when manually typing mount.cifs yaddayadda... But I want it to mount automatically after booting. I tried various different configurations of /etc/fstab and ended up with the following:
//IP-OF-MY-WIN10/kali_share /home/user/Desktop/windows-share cifs rw,vers=default,username=user,password=secret,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix
Note that this works with mount -a, oh and this is on a Kali - just to clarify.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using and if you open a terminal and type mount -a -vvv what result does it give?

Comment: Oops, wrong forum... Am running a kali-distro 4.19.131kali1 but the mount -a -vvv gives: mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.32,unc=\\192.168.0.32\d,vers=default,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,uid=0,gid=0,user=root,prefixpath=Skola/Pentest/kali_share,pass=*******
/root/Desktop/windows-share: successfully mounted